# How to use multi Auth - firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have a register screen that contains "**username, email, phone number, Password**"
and in this case, I use Phone Number Authentication to verify the number so after user verify his number I save his data into firebase DB,

so after that, I navigate hem to **login screen!** that should contain ***Email, Password***  "he registered by them before"

So I don't just compare if his data exist in DB or not,
So it should be used Email/Password Firebase Auth,

But I think it's will take a lot of hits to my Bill or something,

so what you think to achieve these cases because I'm forced to register by Email For Reset Password later?

**here is my register Code**

```
 signUp = async () => {
    const {phoneNumber} = this.state;
    this.setState({message: 'code was sent'});
    const phoneWithAreaCode = phoneNumber.replace(/^0+/, '+972');
    console.log(phoneWithAreaCode);
    auth()
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneWithAreaCode, true)
      .then(confirmResult => {
        console.log('confirmResult', confirmResult);
        this.setState({confirmResult, message: 'code was sent'});
        // this.createUserDatabase();
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Confirmation', {
          message: this.state.message,
          confirmResult: this.state.confirmResult,
          createUser: uid => this.createUserDatabase(uid),
          phoneWithAreaCode: phoneWithAreaCode,
          signInPhoneNumber: phone => auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phone),
        });
      });
  };

  createUserDatabase = uid => {
    const {userName, phoneNumber, email} = this.state;
    // const uid = auth().currentUser.uid;

    const data = {
      uid,
      name: userName,
      email: email,
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
    };

    database()
      .ref(`users/${uid}`)
      .set(data)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('New poll data sent!');
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('Error when creating new poll.', error));
  };
```

Comment: I think firebase auth is free https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44161195/which-pricing-tier-mentions-firebase-authentication

Comment: Thanks, @PeterHaddad can you check this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59088073/how-to-use-email-and-phone-to-authentication-in-firebase